# How to get notification when dynamodb table is autoscaled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to get notification when dynamodb table is autoscaled?
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-scaling-for-amazon-dynamodb/

Answer (score 1):

You can get notification from SNS:

from [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html):

> When one of the CloudWatch alarms is triggered, Amazon SNS sends you a notification (if you have enabled it). The CloudWatch alarm then invokes Application Auto Scaling, which in turn notifies DynamoDB to adjust the ProductCatalog table's provisioned capacity upward or downward, as appropriate.